# Print spaces in Text document if Excel cell is empty

Tags: vba, excel, text

I apologize I am a very noivce VBA user.  What I have been tasked with is to create a text document from an Excel sheet that will be filled in by our sales staff and then be FTPd to our Orders application.  The text file has a set layout and what I am running into is meeting that format.  For example, if the user does not fill in a date in Excel Cell C3 I need the text file to be filled in with six spaces instead of being skipped over.

I tried entering in an IF statement where I am combining the data to write it to the text document, but it errored out with Application-Defined or Object-Defined error and that is a pretty generic error.

Sorry for the cobbled together code, it's the best my simple mind could come up with.  How do I get it to fill in the spaces I need?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim CellData As String
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Range("Home").Select
    CellData = ""
    FilePath = "C:\Users\MN\Desktop\orders.txt"
    Count = ActiveCell.Row - 1

    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Do
        Count = Count + 1
        Range("A" & Count).Select
        ITEMCD = ActiveCell.Value

        If ITEMCD = "" Then
            End
        End If

        CellData = ("26  ") & Format(ActiveCell.Value, "0000000") & _
                   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
                   Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY") & _
                   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
                   Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY")

        Print #1, CellData
        CellData = ""
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I am not receiving an error.  It will write/print to the text document just fine.  What I am having a problem with is if nothing is entered into the Excel cell the output will have nothing there.  For example if I have in the Excel cells from left to right 0401128, 051218, NULL, it will only print 0401128051218, but I need it to print 0401128051218000000.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the lines

```
If ITEMCD = "" Then
        End
    End If
```

it may cause to END the code without closing text file. May try "End do" instead.

Also for Celldata, i think

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
               Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY")
```

repeated twice. if it is the fact and both 2nd & 3rd column is expected to have date, Try something in order

```
CellData = ("26  ") & Format(ActiveCell.Value, "0000000") & _
                   IIf(IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value), "      ", Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, "MMDDYY")) & _
                   IIf(IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value), "      ", Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed.  I do have two dates, one is the store billing date and the other is the delivery date, those follow two different schedules.  I tried the IIf statement and it still is not filling in something if the cell is blank.  Is the IsEmpty formula capturing NULLs?

Comment: In your question you said "filled in with six spaces" but in the comment to Peter T you mentioned "0401128051218000000" which means six zeros. Kindly make it clear. If Six zeros are required then simply replace "      " with "000000" in IIf section. I think isEmpty will cover any blank cell.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it should have read 0401128051218      .  And not 0401128051218000000.  I have tried IsBlank, IsEmpty, IsNull, Trim, etc. and it continues to skip over anything cell that is blank and moves the next cell forward.

Comment: Kindly  give few more details, is the data is entered as text or number or date? What are tbe formats of the cells?  If data is entered as numeric only then  make on display of zeros (file- option- advanced - display section).Edit your post and Try to add few lines of sample data of both input ( excel)  & corresponding output text as image. Try to include a case where 2nd column is blank but 3rd column have data (as blanks at the end of line could not be spoted in the image)

Comment: Ahmed, thank you so very much for sticking with me through this.  I was able to get back to this today and found out that it ended up being user error.  I completely forgot that I was using a command button and kept editing the module and that is why nothing was coming back.  I apologize for all of the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

A `NULL` or empty cell is not interpreted as a numerical value by the VBA code. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
    Dim cellValue as Long
    If Not IsNumeric(ActiveCell) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        cellValue = 0
    Else
        cellValue = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    CellData = ("26  ") & Format(cellValue, "0000000") & _
               ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
               Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY") & _
               ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
               Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, "MMDDYY")
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It helped with the overall code.